# Ansible stops running on a host after an error and I can't use ignore_error

Tags: ansible

During my work on deploying a Kafka Cluster I've noticed that problems might occur if I add a connector to Kafka Connect without first checking if the last added is actively running.

So I have this task:

```yaml
- name: Create connectors 
  include_tasks: connectors_deploy.yml 
  loop: "{{connectors_configs}}"
```

That loops on this data structure

```yaml
connectors_configs:
  - name: debezium-source-mysql
    config_template: debezium_PUT_config.json.j2
    config_file: debezium_PUT_config.json
  - name: debezium_sink
    config_template: debezium_sink.json.j2
    config_file: debezium_sink.json
```

And these are the tasks that are run by the looping task

```yaml
- name: Create connector throught PUT REQUEST
  uri:
    url: "http://{{groups['connect_cluster'][0]}}:8083/connectors/{{item.name}}/config"
    method: PUT
    headers: 
      Content-Type: application/json
    body: "{{ lookup('template', '{{item.config_file}}')}}"
    body_format: json
    status_code: [200, 201, 202]


- name: Check that the connector is up
  uri:
    url: http://{{groups['connect_cluster'][0]}}:8083/connectors/{{item.name}}/status
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
  register: result
  until: result.json.tasks.0.state == "RUNNING"
  retries: 10
  delay: 1
```

The "offending" task is the second one because if any of the responses coming from the Connect REST Api returns a JSON that doesn't adhere to the until's condition Ansible will stop running on the host that caused the error for the rest of the Playbook's execution.

I tried to set `ignore_errors: true` but that simply means that the loop won't rerun again when the until condition isn't met.

So in summary I'd like ansible to repeat the loop's execution until any of the hosts returns the desired outcome and for it to keep on running the remaining Playbook's tasks on the ones that have caused an error.

Is that easily achievable or would it require an hacky solution?

EDIT

As requested here's the error

```
TASK [connectors-config : Check that the connector is up] ***************************************
fatal: [host3]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The conditional check 'result.json.tasks.0.state == "RUNNING"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.json.tasks.0.state == "RUNNING"): list object has no element 0
fatal: [host2]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The conditional check 'result.json.tasks.0.state == "RUNNING"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.json.tasks.0.state == "RUNNING"): list object has no element 0
ok: [host1]

TASK [connectors-config : Create connector throught PUT REQUEST] ********************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [connectors-config : Check that the connector is up] ***************************************
fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The conditional check 'result.json.tasks.0.state == "RUNNING"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.json.tasks.0.state == "RUNNING"): list object has no element 0
```

The errors are expected so I'd like for Ansible to

- retry the loop on EVERY host, even the ones that have thrown an error until I get the expected response from the request from any of the hosts
- to not skip the host that has thrown an error in subsequent tasks

Comment: From the provided information I am not sure what you try to achieve, because variables, content and result examples are missing, but may this can give you hint [Ansible - How to loop over multiple hosts and stop when find correct answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66646577/6771046).

Comment: I wild guess would be `until: "result.json.tasks.0.state | default('') == 'RUNNING'"` because I do suspect this is your actual error, but without the error message in your question, this is just a plain guess, as stated by @U880D

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I've added the error and a little bit more of context as requested

Comment: So, yes, the `default` I raised above would do. Your issue is coming from the fact that, while waiting for your response status to be the requested one, the list `result.json.tasks` is empty (=== `[]`)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε ah yes you are right, now it works beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by β.εηοιτ.βε in the comments the problem lay in the fact that the variable that I'm trying to check is not initialized at the beginning of the task's execution.

Adding a `default` condition inside the `until` parameter solves the issue  and everything works as intended.

```
- name: Check that the connector is up
  uri:
    url: http://{{groups['connect_cluster'][0]}}:8083/connectors/{{item.name}}/status
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
  register: result
  until: "result.json.tasks.0.state | default('') == 'RUNNING'"
  retries: 10
  delay: 1
```